# How to get data from the links in an API?

Tags: javascript, api

I need to get some data from this API-page: https://swapi.dev/api/films/2.
Specifically, I need to get the `name`, `gender`, and `date of birth` of each character from the second episode of Star Wars.

Without problems I can get the main data of the film, such as the title, the director, the producer and so on. However, I cannot get the data of the individual characters.

I tried to do this with just one function and thought it would be useful to create a `for` loop. The loop should `fetch` each result and then return the searched data to me.

```js
async function GetCharacters() {
  const people = fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/").then(data => {
    return data.json();
  }).then(films => {
    console.log(films.characters)
  })

  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    const request = await fetch(film.characters[i]);
    const character = await request.json();
    console.log(character.name)
    console.log(character.gender)
    console.log(character.birth_year)
  }
}

GetCharacters()
```

However, the result I get is different from what I would like:

```js
['https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/4/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/5/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/10/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/13/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/14/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/18/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/20/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/21/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/22/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/23/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/24/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/25/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/26/']
```

Instead of getting the searched data for each character, I get an array of links, as if the loop didn't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

There's two issues here. Firstly, the `people` variable holds a Promise object, not the data returned from the AJAX request. Therefore your `for` loop is not executing. You need to perform the loop through the `characters` array within the callback.

Secondly, you're using `await` in the arrow function which is not async. To fix this you can use the same `fetch().then()` pattern within the loop to retrieve character information:

```js
function GetCharacters() {
  fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/").then(d => d.json()).then(films => {
    films.characters.forEach(url => {
      fetch(url).then(d => d.json()).then(character => {
        console.log(character.name, character.gender, character.birth_year);
        // work with the character data here...
      })
    })
  })
}

GetCharacters()
```